# VBA, array of hashes to array

Tags: arrays, excel, hash, vba

I have a json request from an api in excel and I would like to convert it.

This is what I get:

```
{data:[{price: 3, amount:7},{price: 21, amount:16},{price: 18, amount:4}]}
```

I would like to convert this into:

```
{data:[[3,7],[21,16],[18,4]]}
```

How can I handle this ?

What I'm doing is here sorry about that:

```
text = DownloadTextFile("www../api/etc")
Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(text)
```

Then I would like to loop through;

```
For j = 0 To 100
Range("h" & j) = json(data)(j)(1)
Next j
```

But `Range("h" & j) = json(data)(j)(1)` of course does not work, as it is not an array. That is why I would like to convert it. I don't know how can I loop through the hash and get price and amount data.

I will use the library and write here in case I encounter with a problem, thank you!

Comment: The library most-frequently recommended here is this: https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON.  Try that, and post back with code if you run into problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim newJ, col, col2
    Dim j, o

    Set j = JsonConverter.ParseJson( _
       "{'data':[{'price': 3, 'amount':7},{'price': 21, 'amount':16},{'price': 18, 'amount':4}]}")

    Set col = New Collection

    For Each o In j("data")
        Set col2 = New Collection
        col2.Add o("price")
        col2.Add o("amount")
        col.Add col2
    Next o

    Set newJ = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    newJ.Add "data", col

    Debug.Print JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(newJ)
    '>> {"data":[[3,7],[21,16],[18,4]]}

End Sub
```